# Do Angular Global variables have the same visibility and usage as $scope?

Tags: angularjs

I just now learned that Angular has global variables:

[Angular Values](http://pterkildsen.com/2012/11/16/angularjs-tips-and-tricks/)

```
var app = angular.module('mySuperDuperApp', ['SomeExternalModule']);

// Define global variables
app.value('globals', {
        db : null,
        databasename : "serviceapp",
        image_max_height: 620,
        image_quality: 0.7
    }
);
```

Some questions regarding usage.

- Can a global variable have its value changed?
- To change it (if possible) can I just refer to it by it's name such as db in any controller script?
- Can I access a global variable in my HTML with just the name only?

Comment: Where did you learn that? I can't see anything mentioning globals in the official documentation.

Comment: I haven't come across globals like that before, almost certainly you shouldn't be using them, using $scope, $rootScope or defining a Service is the "Angular way" of sharing data across the scope of your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `inject` those values just like you would inject a controller or a service and can modify them just like you would any other injected object.

```js
app.controller("mySuperDuperController", function ($scope, 'globals') {
  $scope.globals = globals;   // <-- to access them in the template
  globals.db = 'newDb';       // <-- modify their value.
});
```

Answer (score 5):

A variable loaded into a `value` provider isn't really a global in the traditional sense.  It doesn't sit in the global name space. The provider needs to be injected anywhere you use it so it's a bit more akin to an object in an OO sense.

A `value` provider is a way to allow many different components access to a variable, so I see why you're calling it a global.  But a `value` is a good way to share data without many of the risks of actual globals.

You might check out the different kinds of providers here [Provider docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide) of which you'll see `value` is just one.

1) You can change an Angular `value`  (but not a `const` which is closely related)

2) You need to inject the `value` wherever you use it and then prefix it with the name of your `value` For example:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, global ) {
     console.log(global.db);
     global.databasename = "newname"; 
});
```

3) You can access the value from HTML if you copy the value on to the appropriate scope:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, global ) {
     $scope.db = global.db;
});
```